# subsetting from same-named data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame called `c41` ([HERE](https://github.com/izeh/l/blob/master/c4.csv)). Some column names (e.g., `type`) in this data frame are repeated once or twice. As a result, data.frame adds a `".number"` suffix to distinguish between them.

Suppose I want to subset variable `type == 3` among all column names that have a `"type"` root in their names. Currently, I drop the `".number"` suffixes and then `subset` but that incorrectly returns nothing.

**Question:** **In BASE R**, how can I subset a variable value (`type == 3`) without needing to include the `".number"` suffixes (e.g., `type == 3` instead of `type.1 == 3`)?

In other words, how can I find any `"type"` whose value is 3 regardless of its numeric suffix.

```
c41 <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/l/master/c4.csv")

c42 <- setNames(c41, sub("\\.\\d+$", "", names(c41))) # Take off the `".number"` suffixes

subset(c42, type == 3) # Now subset ! But it return nothing!
```

Comment: @H1, I upvoted your comment but if you want please provide that as a response so I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renaming the columns to make them non-unique is a recipe for a headache and is not advisable. Without renaming the columns, in base R you could do something like this instead:

```
c41[rowSums(c41[grep("^type", names(c41))] == 3, na.rm = TRUE) > 0,]
```

I don't think `subset()` can be used here if column names are duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I see that you edited your question to specify base R. Can't help you there! But perhaps a `dplyr` solution is of interest.

You can use `dplyr::filter_at` and the `starts_with` helper.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

c4 <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/l/master/c4.csv")
c4 %>% 
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("type")), any_vars(. == 3))
```

Adding a `select_at` to display just the relevant columns:

```
c4 %>% 
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("type")), any_vars(. == 3)) %>% 
  select_at(vars(starts_with("type")))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
   type type_1
  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1      3
2     2      3
```